# Status of sysstat.service showing active(exited)

Tags: systemd, init, sysvinit

When I see status of `sysstat` is see the following,

```
● sysstat.service - Resets System Activity Logs
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysstat.service; enabled; 
vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-11-28 11:46:45 EST; 4s ago
Process: 4159 ExecStart=/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 --boot (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 4159 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 28 11:46:45 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Resets System 
Activity Logs...
Nov 28 11:46:45 localhost systemd[1]: Started Resets System 
Activity Logs.
```

Also couldn’t find any `pid` specified above.

Question is, why this happens?

Comment: Deleted assumption as wrong assumption is pointless.

Comment: Oneshot run, after which the regular performance capture is via cron, e.g. `/etc/cron.d/sysstat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. sysstat is a "oneshot" type service, meaning it executes once and then it exits:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/sysstat.service

#... elided ...

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 --boot

#... elided ...
```

... which explains why there is no PID -- because there is no process any more.

The [documentation for systemd services](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) says, in part:

> Behavior of oneshot is similar to simple; however, it is expected that the process has to exit before systemd starts follow-up units.